# what are the main differences between parametric and non-parametric machine learning algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, nonparametric, gaussian-mixture-distribution, computer-vision, time-complexity

I am interested in parametric and non-parametric machine learning algorithms, their advantages and disadvantages and also their main differences regarding computational complexities. In particular I am interested in the parametric Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) and the non-parametric kernel density estimation (KDE). As I understood it that if a "small" number of data points is used then parametric (like GMM/EM) are the better choice but if the amount of data points increases to a much higher number then non-parametric algorithms are better. Could someone please explain both in bit more detail regarding comparison?

Comment: Why did you include the `computer-vision` tag? Is your question specific to that area of application?

Comment: what source said GMM specifically is better than KDE for small sample sizes?

Comment: @RichardHardy This question relates, among other things, to the topic of Computer Vision/Image Processing

Comment: @develarist That is what I was mainly able to take from some papers. Do you have a different point of view?

Comment: I am not contending it. It is a general statement to say that parametric models, instead of empirical models, should be used for small sample sizes. everyone knows that. so there would probably be more specific reasons why GMM would be more appropriate than KDE for small sample sizes beyond just the reasons put forth through the general statement. and I'm sure there might be something about GMM that sets it apart, so that's why I'm asking. To be honest, GMM and KDE aren't intended to be direct contenders. one is a mixture model, the other is not

Comment: @develarist I changed "I found out" with "as I understood it" in the question. I don't want to confuse people. I'm just a beginner in this field and trying to better understand it and get some detailed information here.

Comment: @develarist it is not the case that parametric models should be used for small sample sizes.  For example in the realm of statistical methods, with small samples we don't have enough information to assess model assumptions and tend to use nonparametric and semiparametric methods.

Comment: when I gave credence to empirical estimation for small sample sizes I received alot of pushback for some reason. it seems like there is no consensus so I gave up and played up parametric models to stay out of fights. what would you do to prove them wrong?

Comment: @develarist, what do you mean by *empirical models*?

Comment: Non-parametric models